# Check if user is signed in or not under flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am using firebase as a backend in my flutter app.I want to know how can I get to know if the user is signed in or not in app.

Someone please let me know as I am a beginner with flutter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null
```